# Flite Text to Speech not working properly

Tags: raspberry-pi3, flite

I tried following [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/speech-synthesis-on-the-raspberry-pi/speak-easier-flite) post to get flite tts to work on raspberry pi 3, but unfortunately when I try

```
flite -t "word"
```

Nothing is read out but when I try

```
flite -t "All good men come to the aid of the rebellion"
```

Only "come to the aid of the rebellion" is read out. Any help on how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I just tried it and I had no problems

Comment: When I try it on my pi 3, the first two or three words are not read out. Just the remaining words. If it's just a word then nothing is read at all. Can't seem to figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and Reinstalling flite solved the problem.