# Flite doesn't produce speech without creating a .WAV file?

Tags: c, text-to-speech, flite

I am trying to run flite TTS for a project, and I encountering an issue where there's no output sound when I run this command.

```
flite -t hello
```

But, when I run this command, it creates a .wav file and I can play it.

```
flite -t hello -o hello.wav
```

I managed to compile with the correct libraries and downloaded the required voice files {[source code](https://github.com/festvox/flite)} so there are no issues there, and after looking in Stackoverflow I found a few questions posted about this{[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383392/flite-text-to-speech-not-working-properly)}, but none of them works with mine. Also, I tried running the sample C code given in the flite's documentation {[doc](http://www.festvox.org/flite/doc/flite.pdf)}, but that doesn't produce any output speech either.

```
//extracted from the sample code
flite_file_to_speech(argv[1],v,"play");
```

Could anyone suggest me a way to generate the speech with flite, without creating a .wav file?

Comment: Perhaps the program is unable to detect the correct output destination (e.g. speakers)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is there a way to select the speakers in the config file?